# check if post return value after promises.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this:

```
var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();

promises.push(
  post.once('value').then((snapshot2) => Object.assign(snapshot2.val(), {
    key: snapshot2.key,
    likeOrNot: likeOrNot
  })));
```

if posts/value if not a valid value in posts I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I'd like to check before push if post !== null or something like this to avoid this error.

Any ideas what I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists) method of the `DataSnapshot` and do as follows:

```
var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();
promises.push(post.once('value'));

// ...

return Promise.all(promises)
.then(dataSnapshots => {

  const objectsArray = [];
  dataSnapshots.forEach(snap => 
     if (snap.exists()) {
         objectsArray.push(
           Object.assign(snap.val(), {key: snap.key, likeOrNot: likeOrNot})
         )
     }

  // ...
  // return ... 
})
```

To be fine tuned as necessary!! (you may not need an `objectsArray` array...)